# How to get parameters from Next.js when post communication from axios

Tags: next.js, axios

How do I get parameters from the api code in Next.js when I post-communicate in axios?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dqGcd.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gZj9I.jpg)

ReadableStream {locked: false, state: 'readable', supportBYOB: false} appears when taken to the console.

Comment: You need to update those images, better if you could paste the code snippets directly